# Using algebraic identities to prove a number is not prime

Tags: contest-math

$$3^{3^n}(3^{3^n}+1)+3^{3^n +1}-1$$
I want the prove that the number is not prime. I used the identity $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc $. I couldn't simplify to the state where the factors could be observed.

Comment: Have you tried to check if it is divisible by $2$ ? As a hint, notice that $3^{3^n}$ and $3^{3^n}+1$ are two consecutive integers

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested that $$a=3^{3^{n-1}} , b=9^{3^{n-1}}, c=-1$$ I can't get it. How could I derive those terms from the equation. Then, followed by the identity $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$$

Comment: Ah okay, first recall below property of exponents $$(a^\color{red}{m})^n = a^{m\times n}$$

Comment: Next see if you can answer below $$\left(3^{\color{red}{3^{n-1}}}\right)^{3} = ?$$

Comment: If we use the identity to prove, I couldn't get it.

Comment: Give it a try and see

Comment: I mean how does it relate to this identity, when the term $-3abc$ is unclear.

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain directly. Lets take this slow and step by step. I want you to try answering my question first ?

Comment: Sure, I was confused by the b term

Comment: Okay I see what you're asking. Let me grab a paper and pen, one minute..

Comment: Got it. Just convince yourself that below is true : $$3^{3^n} * 3^{3^n} = 3^{2*3^n} = 9^{3^n} = \left(9^{3^{n-1}}\right)^3$$

Comment: How about the 1 still in $$3^{3^n }+1$$

Comment: I mean I couldn't figure out why. Supposed b is $3^{3^n +1}$  and the a term as follow in the question but how could we get the b term to be $9^{3^{n-1}}$ as the solution suggested.

Comment: $$3^{3^n}(3^{3^n}+1)+3^{3^n +1}-1$$

Hey its easy if you take it step by step, first distribute into the parenthesis and see what you get

Comment: Is this supposed that the term $-3abc$ is a zero

Comment: Can you distribute below ? $$3^{3^n}(3^{3^n}+1) = ?$$

Comment: $9^{3^n}+3^{3^n}$

Comment: Yes, next see that $$9^{3^n} =  \left(9^{3^{n-1}}\right)^3 $$

Comment: That is your $b^3$ term

Comment: Yes , this is true

Comment: $$9^{3^n}+3^{3^n}  = b^3 + a^3$$

where $b = 9^{3^{n-1}}$ and $a = 3^{3^{n-1}}$

Comment: For the a term is it $4*3^{3^n}$

Comment: With me so far ?

Comment: If so how to actually get $3^{3^{n-1}}$

Comment: You get that from $$3^{3^n}$$

Comment: First notice below $$3^{3^n} = 3^{3^{n-1}\times 3}$$

Comment: okay I've to consider the further power n

Comment: Its really easy if you relax and take a good look :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been working on this for 2 hours.

Comment: Np :) Actually I was lying when I said "its really easy". Now that I look back, it looks a lot confusing manipulating with exponents... Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

define
$$  w = 3^{3^n} $$

Your number is then
$$  w(w+1) + 3 w - 1 = w^2 +w + 3w -1 = w^2 + 4 w -1  $$

Now, $w$ is odd, so $w^2$ is odd, so $w^2 + 4 w -1$ is even. Also, $w \geq 3,$ so $w^2 + 4 w -1$ is bigger than 4 and even, therefore not prime.

Answer (score 0):

The other approach does show a quite large factor of the number; good to know how to approach this.

The expression $$ 3^{3^n} 3^{3^n} + 3^{3^n} + 3^{3^n + 1} - 1  $$
first becomes
$$  9^{3^n} + 3^{3^n} + 3^{3^n + 1} - 1 $$

The first two terms really are cubes, since the exponents are divisible by 3. If we look for $a^3 = 3^{3^n},$ it is reasonable to try
$$ a = 3^x  $$
because we want a power of three. Then
$$  a^3 = \left(3^x \right)^3 = 3^{3x}. $$
Then $a^3 = 3^{3^n}$ tells us
$$  3^{3x} = 3^{3^n} $$
so
$$ 3x = 3^n $$ and
$$ x = 3^n 3^{-1} = 3^{n-1},  $$
$$ a = 3^x = 3^{3^{n-1}}  $$
$$  $$
 If we look for $b^3 = 9^{3^n},$ it is reasonable to try
$$ b = 9^y  $$
because we want a power of nine. Then
$$  b^3 = \left(9^y \right)^3 = 9^{3y}. $$
Then $b^3 = 9^{3^n}$ tells us
$$  9^{3y} = 9^{3^n} $$
so
$$ 3y = 3^n $$ and
$$ y = 3^n 3^{-1} = 3^{n-1},  $$
$$ b = 9^x = 9^{3^{n-1}}  $$
$$  $$
We are not yet sure what we want to use for $c.$ Let us examine what we already have for $3ab,$ anticipating the eventual $-3abc.$

$$  a b = 3^{3^{n-1}} 9^{3^{n-1}}  $$

MORE TO COME 11:08 am

We do need to understand $b = a^2.$ Well,
$$ a^2 = \left( 3^{3^{n-1}}\right)^2 = 3^{ 2 \cdot 3^{n-1}} $$ while
$$ b = \left( 3^2 \right)^{3^{n-1}} = 3^{ 2 \cdot 3^{n-1}} \; .  $$
So $b = a^2,$ also $ab = a a^2 = a^3$ so
$$ ab = 3^{3^n} \; .  $$ Next
$$ 3ab = 3 \cdot 3^{3^n} = 3^1 \cdot 3^{3^n} =  \cdot 3^{3^n + 1} \; .$$
This is progress. We now have the overall expression
$$  9^{3^n} + 3^{3^n} + 3^{3^n + 1} - 1 = b^3 + a^3 + 3ab - 1. $$
We can introduce a value of $c$ by demanding $-3abc = 3ab.$ The requires $c=-1.$ We have 
$$ b^3 + a^3 - 3abc - 1.   $$
Finally $c^3 = (-1)^3 = -1,$ and we get
$$  9^{3^n} + 3^{3^n} + 3^{3^n + 1} - 1 = b^3 + a^3 - 3abc - c^3 = a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc. $$

Perhaps I should say why the new factors are both large. We have
$$a+b+c > b  = 9^{3^{n-1}}$$
It is also worth remembering that
$$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - bc - ca - ab = \frac{1}{2} \left( (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2 + (a-b)^2  \right)  $$
which is bigger than $ (b+1)^2 / 2 \; > \; b^2 / 2 \; . $